# Let the webview keep the same content when slide the keyboard?

Tags: android, webview

When user slide the hard keyboard, my activity will re-create, the web view in the activity will also re-load the page. 
for our app's framework's limitation, I can not change the onConfigChange in android manifest. 
I would like to find a way, let the activity re-create, while keep the webview as before (do not re-load the page).

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy()` will be able to save the Parcelable data from when your application was destroyed, and `onResume()` should be able to reconstruct it. If by some magic you're able to save the entire page state and reload it, this would be the route you take. Otherwise, you should consider a less restrictive framework.